# AngularJS : how to properly use Math.pow in filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJs & still learning JS and not skilled in maths so please, be gentle :)

I'm trying to make a loan calulator for a mobile app for my company. 
I would like to make one which can auto-refresh the result when a value is change to get rid of the "result/ calculate" button.

I take a look at Angular filters, it's pretty easy to build a simple math formula, but exponent values give me headache...
I've find on Stackoverflow how to use a filter to use Math.pow with Angular Filters, but i just can't resolve the [formula](http://www.guideducredit.com/HTMcorps/Fichierssimulateurs/math.htm)...

This is the formula i have to build :

**m** = Monthly payment

**K** = Kapital

**R** = Rate %

**n** = Period of payement, in years

**m = [( K * R ) / 12] / [ 1 - ( 1 + ( R / 12 )) ^-n]**

For 1000000 capital, 60 years  and 5% rate, the answer should be 4386.42

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {

$scope.Math = window.Math;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        
        <form>
        <div class="item">
            <label>Capital</label>
            <input type="range" id="loan" name="loan" ng-model="capital" min="10000" max="1000000" step="10000" value="10000">
            <h1>{{capital}}</h1>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="item">
            <label>Number of years</label>
            <input type="range" id="duree" name="duree" ng-model="time" min="0" max="60" step="5" value="1">
            <h1>{{time}}</h1>
        </div>
        <hr>
            
            <div class="item">
            <label>rate %</label>
            <input type="range" id="duree" name="rate" ng-model="rate" min="1" max="15" step="0.1" value="1">
            <h1>{{rate}}</h1>
        </div>
                
        <div class="item">
            <h1>Monthly payment : {{((capital * (rate /1200) * (time / 12))/12) + (capital / time)  | number:2 }}</h1>
            <h2 >
                
                          

        
            </h2>
        </div>
                       

    </form>
    </div>    
</div>
```

A jsFiddle demo here :
http://jsfiddle.net/_Arn__/nruqk9z8/5/

Could someone help me on this, please ?

Regards,
Arno

Comment: Why in the world would you want to make that kind of calculation in the html template instead of the controller ?

Comment: I'm not very aware how controllers works, i'm pretty new to Angular. I already have a JS formula i could import, but it doesn't auto-refresh the result.

Comment: You literally answered your question then. Read up on controllers. I'm absolutely convinced that if you read a couple of examples of angularjs code you will figure it out. I'm not trying to be mean but ..... do a bit of research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think n should be months (n*12):

```
//m = Monthly payment
//K = Kapital
//R = Rate %
//n = Period of payement, in years

var m ;
var K = 1000000;
var R = 0.05;
var n = 60*12;

var dnmntr = ( 1 + ( R / 12 ));
var nmrtr = ( K * R )/12;
m = nmrtr / (1-Math.pow(dnmntr,-n));
console.log(m);
```

Prints: 4386.418998606701

Comment: Thank you Irnop, i'll check that.